# authenticate AWS ElastiCache for Redis using an IAM role

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, identity-management

I am trying to authenticate AWS ElastiCache for Redis using an IAM role instead of a username and password.
I have successfully authenticated with the Redis cache with username/password using the following code:

csharp code

```
using StackExchange.Redis;

string connectionString = "{redis-hostURL}:6379,ssl=true,User={username},password={password}";
var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
var redisDatabase = redisConnection.GetDatabase();
redisDatabase.StringSet("MyKey", "My Value");
Console.WriteLine(redisDatabase.StringGet("MyKey"));
```

My application is built on .NET 6, and I have configured AWS ElastiCache with an IAM user.

I would like to authenticate using the IAM role, but I haven't been able to find any .NET code examples for this.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line

Comment: I'm Loogking for Amazon Elasticache with IAM role authentication

Comment: There are two parts to IAM 1) Login 2) Access to resources.  IAM Authentication to Amazon is no different than an other IAM server.  See : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/security-101/what-is-identity-access-management-iam.  Amazon Elasticache is a higher level language that makes it easier to access data.  You first have to use normal IAM login before you can start using Elasticache.  The following like may help : https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/

Comment: Actually I'm looking for c# code sample/Package that allowed me to connect AWS redis  with IAM role.

Comment: See following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Clusters.RBAC.html?force_isolation=true  The json code which is the body of the http request would be the same for any language.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I have checked, In IAM role authentication able to get secrate key token.
But 
- As my code connection string only accepting Username/Password.
- I have examined some packages, but they only accept a username and password, not accept credential or secret key token. I have also try passing token/Secratekey as password but got no luck.

Comment: See Migrating from RBAC to Redis AUTH at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/auth.html?force_isolation=true.  The authentication policy set at the server has to be consistent with the one used by client.